# Getting embeddings from wav2vec2 models in HuggingFace

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, pre-trained-model

I am trying to get the embeddings from pre-trained wav2vec2 models (e.g., from jonatasgrosman/wav2vec2-large-xlsr-53-german) using my own dataset.

My aim is to use these features for a downstream task (not specifically speech recognition). Namely, since the dataset is relatively small, I would train an SVM with these embeddings for the final classification.

So far I have tried this:

```
model_name = "facebook/wav2vec2-large-xlsr-53-german"
feature_extractor = Wav2Vec2Processor.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = Wav2Vec2Model.from_pretrained(model_name)

input_values = feature_extractor(train_dataset[:10]["speech"], return_tensors="pt", padding=True, 
                                 feature_size=1, sampling_rate=16000 ).input_values
```

Then, I am not sure whether the embeddings here correspond to the sequence of last_hidden_states:

```
hidden_states = model(input_values).last_hidden_state
```

or to the sequence of features of the last conv layer of the model:

```
features_last_cnn_layer = model(input_values).extract_features
```

Also, is this the correct way to extract features from a pre-trained model?

How one can get embeddings from a specific layer?

PD: Posting here as the HuggingFace's forum seems to be less active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/wav2vec2.html#transformers.models.wav2vec2.modeling_wav2vec2.Wav2Vec2BaseModelOutput):

> last_hidden_state (torch.FloatTensor of shape (batch_size,
> sequence_length, hidden_size)) – Sequence of hidden-states at the
> output of the last layer of the model.
>
> extract_features (torch.FloatTensor of shape (batch_size,
> sequence_length, conv_dim[-1])) – Sequence of extracted feature
> vectors of the last convolutional layer of the model.

- The last_hidden_state vector represents so called `contextualized embeddings` (i.e. every feature (CNN output) has a vector representation that is to some extend influenced by the other tokens of the sequence).
- The extract_features vector represents the embeddings of your input (after the CNNs).
  .

> Also, is this the correct way to extract features from a pre-trained
> model?
> Yes.

> How one can get embeddings from a specific layer?
> Set `output_hidden_states=True`:

```
o = model(input_values,output_hidden_states=True)
o.keys()
```

Output:

```
odict_keys(['last_hidden_state', 'extract_features', 'hidden_states'])
```

The `hidden_states` value contains the embeddings and the contextualized embeddings of each attention layer.

P.S.: [jonatasgrosman/wav2vec2-large-xlsr-53-german](https://huggingface.co/jonatasgrosman/wav2vec2-large-xlsr-53-german) model was trained with `feat_extract_norm`==layer. That means, you should also pass an attention mask to the model:

```py
model_name = "facebook/wav2vec2-large-xlsr-53-german"
feature_extractor = Wav2Vec2Processor.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = Wav2Vec2Model.from_pretrained(model_name)

i= feature_extractor(train_dataset[:10]["speech"], return_tensors="pt", padding=True, 
                                 feature_size=1, sampling_rate=16000 )
model(**i)
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess it would depend on the case, but, what embeddings would be a better choice? those of the last_hidden_states or those from the last CNN layer? Regarding the last part about passing the attentions to the model, then the way to get the embeddings would be: " outs = model(**input_values);  embs = outs.extract_features"?

Comment: It depends on the use case. For most cases I can think of right now, I would use the contextualized embeddings (i.e. last_hidden_states). `outs` is an object that contains `extract_features` and `last_hidden_states`. You can access its members with `outs.extract_features` or `outs["extract_features"]`.

Comment: Ok. Just one more question about the wav2vec2 stuff. So in the docs there are wav2vec2Model, wav2vec2ForCTC, wav2vec2ForSequenceClassification, and wav2vec2ForPreTraining. I couldn't quite catch the differences among them tho. My doubt is if I use  "[any_of_them].from_ptretrained", will the resulting embeddings be greatly different?

Comment: Use `wav2vec2Model`, it is the correct class for your use case. `wav2vec2ForCTC` is for [CTC](https://distill.pub/2017/ctc/) (i.e. transcription).  `wav2vec2ForSequenceClassification` is for classifiying the audio sequence (e.g. music genres). `wav2vec2ForPreTraining` is for training a new model. @jvel07